# Transpose sequence of integers into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A table contains only one column with sequence of integers:

```
1
2
3
4
...
20
```

Is it possible to transpose it into table with three columns with the only one query?
So the result should be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
...
19 20 null
```

Comment: How would that be useful? (I.e. could you please describe *why* you'd like to do this, there may be other ways to achieve the same). One particular reason why I'm asking is that the order is not guaranteed (unless you use `order by` clause) and with a single source column you don't have exactly a lot of options to order by.

Comment: It isn't deal with some business logic, just a question that I though about this evening, and it's just interesting is this possible to do without cycling/creating temp table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select myCol,
        floor((row_number() over (order by myCol)-1)/3) rn,
        (row_number() over (order by myCol)-1) % 3 + 1 cn
 from myTable)
select [1],[2],[3]
from
(select * from cte) as src
 pivot
(max(myCol) 
 for cn in ([1],[2],[3])) as pvt
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2be9b/11).

Comment: The result is only one row: [19, 20, 18]

Comment: @user2468974: A slightly different version in the SQLFiddle - my answer now amended accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id INT)
INSERT INTO @temp (id)
VALUES 
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),
    (11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)

SELECT [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
    SELECT 
          id
        , rn = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 3 + 1
        , rn2 = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) / 3
    FROM @temp
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(id)
    FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3])
) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
declare @t table (n int)
insert into @t values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13)

select n0, n1, n2

from (
    select n0, r from (
        select n [n0], row_number() over (order by n) - 1 [r]
        from @t 
    ) t0
) tt0

left join (
    select n1, r
    from (
        select n [n1], row_number() over (order by n) - 1 [r]
        from @t 
    ) t1
    where t1.r % 3 = 1
) tt1 on (tt1.r / 3) = tt0.r / 3

left join (
    select n2, r
    from (
        select n [n2], row_number() over (order by n) - 1 [r]
        from @t 
    ) t2
    where t2.r % 3 = 2
) tt2 on (tt2.r / 3) = tt0.r / 3


where tt0.r % 3 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If by sequence you mean that the values simply increment by 1, then you can basically do this with arithmetic:

```
select mycol,
       (case when mycol + 1 <= maxval then mycol + 1 end),
       (case when mycol + 2 <= maxval then mycol + 2 end)
from myTable cross join
     (select min(myCol)%3 as offset,
             max(myCol) as maxval
      from myTable
     ) const
where (mycol - offset)%3 = 0;
```

The other solutions are more general -- they will pivot any values in the sequence.  This specifically pivots only numbers that increment by 1.